# What event is responsible for actions when time is out in Timer Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

My program is some kind of test. The time of passing test is limited(20 minutes). When the time is out, the test must be finished and `MessageBox` appears with results of test. In `Form_Load` :

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Interval = (1000) * (1);
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            timer_label.Text = Convert.ToString(time);
            --time;
        }
```

How to finish test when `time == 0`? And why time in `timer_label` changes with step 2?(e.g. 1999, 1997, 1995...)

Comment: No, I decrement time only once

Comment: Is it possible you've assigned the Tick event to be handled more than once?

Answer (score 2):

> How to finish test when time == 0?

Timer just raises even on some interval. You should start timer for that. If you don't want events to be raised anymore, you should stop timer. You can do it directly in `Tick` event handler:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    timer_label.Text = Convert.ToString(time);
    time--;

    if (time == 0)
       timer1.Stop();
}
```

Second question:

> And why time in timer_label changes with step 2?(e.g. 1999, 1997,
>   1995...)

From your code there is no reason for such behavior. Looks like you have subscribed to two timers, or you have two event handlers of same timer `Tick` event. Also make sure you don't have decrement operator when displaying time, something like this:

```
timer_label.Text = Convert.ToString(--time);
--time;
```

Comment: @GrantWinney agree, this check will be more appropriate then. But I hope bug will be fixed :)

Comment: This will only stop the timer not the test. The user can continue answering the questions

Comment: @ManishDalal what code should be executed to stop test?

Comment: Depends on the context. some ideas out of my mind are: disable all controls, Hide this form, Hide the panel and show results panel, etc :)

Comment: @ManishDalal yep, I also don't know what OP means by ending test. Main idea is do this when time is out (i.e. equals 0). And we know how to handle that (sample above) :)